# Only show download button when a gallery image has that tag?

Tags: fancybox

Is there a way to only show the download button for gallery images that have the data-download-src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You could use events to toggle download button, example:

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
  Toolbar: {
    display: ["counter", "download", "thumbs", "close"],
  },
  on: {
    "ready Carousel.change": function (fancybox) {
      const src = fancybox.getSlide().$trigger.dataset.downloadSrc;

      document
        .querySelectorAll(".fancybox__button--download")
        .forEach((node) => {
          if (src) {
            node.style.display = "";
          } else {
            node.style.display = "none";
          }
        });
    },
  },
});
```

Demo - https://fancyapps.com/playground/1mV